# How do I set up my model class for nested JSON responses?

Tags: json, api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using the HttpClient in a C# application to access a web API. I'm new to this kind of web API (I usually do WCF services).

One of the responses looks like this:

```
{
    "access_token": the access token,
    "scope": "read",
    "expires_in": seconds to expiry,
    "refresh_token": a refresh token
}
```

And the model class looks like this:

```
class AuthResponse
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
}
```

So when I do:

```
var result = resposne.Content.ReadAsAsync<AuthResponse>().Result;
```

I get an AuthResponse object back with its values filled in. Magic.

The next bit of API returns a response like this:

```
{
    "data": {
         "visible": boolean,
         "email": valid e-mail string or null,
         "location_string": human-readable location identifier string,
         "ad_id": primary key of the ad
    }, 
    "actions": {
         "change_form": URL to change this ad
         "public_view": URL to view this ad's public HTML page
         "html_edit": URL to view this ad's HTML edit page 
                      that has more options than the API change_form does
    }
}
```

What would my model class look like? How do I account for the nesting?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't solved this by now this is what I have found:

I found this to be great:

http://json2csharp.com

You simply paste your JSON url or even your JSON into it and it will return you a model class, with nesting. Alternatively you can copy your JSOn and Edit > Paste Special > in Visual studio, which will return your model class too.